# Automatic scroller for a Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, xaml

I am working on a WPF application called by a powershell script, where all my functions are.
My application has textboxes where you put hostnames, usernames, and the buttons give information like storage, local users, applications installed, etc... All these information are printed in a read-only textbox (so that I may copy-pasta).

**THE PROBLEM** :
I figured how to put a scroll bar in this textbox, but I would like it to scroll to bottom each time a button is pressed.

Here is the line of my textbox in XAML :

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtResults" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="320" Margin="144,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="516" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
```

And, for example, here is how I associate a button to a powershell function :

```
$var_btnInstalledSoftwares.Add_Click( {
    $var_txtResults.Text += Get-Softs -Computer $var_txtComputer.Text
})
```

Can you please help me ?

**NOTE :** the output of the above function is a table with strings

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ScrollToEnd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.scrolltoend?view=netcore-3.1) method in the event handler.

```
$var_btnInstalledSoftwares.Add_Click( {
    $var_txtResults.Text += Get-Softs -Computer $var_txtComputer.Text
    $var_txtResults.ScrollToEnd()
})
```